# thermal cutoff switch keeps tripping kenmore he2

Tags: dryer

My electric Kenmore HE2 thermal cutoff switch keeps tripping.  Replaced the switch and heating element and still trips.  Seem to have good airflow and cleaned the vent pipe.  Thermal cutoff keeps tripping.

Comment: What model is the dryer?  Can you measure how hot the exhaust air (or the air in the drum) is getting?

Answer (score 1):

The model is a Kenmore HE2 11087561603.  I just replaced the thermal cutoff and the high limit thermostat, which I hadn't replaced yet.  The machine is working fine now with no problems.  My mistake was not replacing the high limit thermostat and the thermal cutoff at the same time.  Based on the results, the high limit thermostat was the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused when lint or socks are clogging  up the vent way paths within the dryer or the vent pipe to the outside.  How long is the vent pipe? Is it properly sized and not squashed behind the dryer? When you pull the lint trap is there evidence of lint down there?
A distinct second likelihood: , there is another thermal sensor that causes the heat coil to cycle on and off as the dryer functions.  This one is not a switch, but a two wire device called a thermistor.  Its resistance changes as it heats and tell the circuitry when to cut in and out the heat relay.  A symptom of this being bad will be the heat remaining always on, even when set to "low" heat.  And it will heat up to the point that the thermal safety cut off triggers.  That component is a cheap and easy fix once the machine is apart...